# TensorFlowOpLayer messes up the TensorBoard graphs

Tags: keras, tensorboard, tensorflow2.x

This question is about TensorFlow (and TensorBoard) version 2.2rc3, but I have experienced the same issue with 2.1. It is a continuation of the question '[Messed up TensorBoard graphs due to Python operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61581114/messed-up-tensorboard-graphs-due-to-python-operations)'.

Consider the following code:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(784, ))    

outputs = tf.zeros([32, 10], tf.float32)

for i in range(0, 3):
    x = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', name='Model/Block' + str(i) + '/relu')(inputs) 
    x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, name='Model/Block' + str(i) + '/dropout')(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='Model/Block' + str(i) + '/softmax')(x)
    outputs = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1], name='Model/add/add' + str(i))([outputs, x])

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.summary(line_length=100, positions=[.45, .58, .67, 1.])

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784).astype('float32') / 255

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

logdir = "logs/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=32,
          epochs=5,
          validation_split=0.2,
          callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

When run, it prints the following summary:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                          Output Shap Param  Connected to               
====================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)                  [(None, 784 0                                 
____________________________________________________________________________________
Model/Block0/relu (Dense)             (None, 32)  25120  input_1[0][0]              
____________________________________________________________________________________
Model/Block0/dropout (Dropout)        (None, 32)  0      Model/Block0/relu[0][0]    
____________________________________________________________________________________
Model/Block1/relu (Dense)             (None, 32)  25120  input_1[0][0]              
____________________________________________________________________________________
Model/Block0/softmax (Dense)          (None, 10)  330    Model/Block0/dropout[0][0] 
____________________________________________________________________________________
Model/Block1/dropout (Dropout)        (None, 32)  0      Model/Block1/relu[0][0]    
____________________________________________________________________________________
Model/Block2/relu (Dense)             (None, 32)  25120  input_1[0][0]              
____________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_AddV2 (TensorFlowOpLayer) [(32, 10)]  0      Model/Block0/softmax[0][0] 
____________________________________________________________________________________
Model/Block1/softmax (Dense)          (None, 10)  330    Model/Block1/dropout[0][0] 
____________________________________________________________________________________
Model/Block2/dropout (Dropout)        (None, 32)  0      Model/Block2/relu[0][0]    
____________________________________________________________________________________
Model/add/add1 (Lambda)               (32, 10)    0      tf_op_layer_AddV2[0][0]    
                                                         Model/Block1/softmax[0][0] 
____________________________________________________________________________________
Model/Block2/softmax (Dense)          (None, 10)  330    Model/Block2/dropout[0][0] 
____________________________________________________________________________________
Model/add/add2 (Lambda)               (32, 10)    0      Model/add/add1[0][0]       
                                                         Model/Block2/softmax[0][0] 
====================================================================================
```

Note the strange entry `tf_op_layer_AddV2 (TensorFlowOpLayer)`. This kind of entry makes the TensorBoard graphs very messy. It turns out that when avoiding the use of the `tf.zeros()`, this strange `tf_op_layer_AddV2` element is not added. So the following code will not generate any `tf_op_layer` element:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(784, ))

x = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', name='Model/Block0/relu')(inputs) 
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, name='Model/Block0/dropout')(x)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='Model/Block0/softmax')(x)

for i in range(1, 3):
    x = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', name='Model/Block' + str(i) + '/relu')(inputs) 
    x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, name='Model/Block' + str(i) + '/dropout')(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='Model/Block' + str(i) + '/softmax')(x)
    outputs = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1], name='Model/add/add' + str(i))([outputs, x])

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.summary(line_length=84, positions=[.46, .60, .69, 1.])

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784).astype('float32') / 255

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

logdir = "logs/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=32,
          epochs=5,
          validation_split=0.2,
          callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

There are many more complex examples where the `tf_op_layer_` elements are created. It will be appreciated if it is exaplained why they are created and how to avoid them.

Comment: It should be added that if a name is given to `tf.zeros()` (e.g. `outputs = tf.zeros([32, 10], tf.float32, name='Model/add/zeros')`, this has no effect.

Comment: I have submitted an issue in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39398 and will update this post with the results from there.